# regex split string into groups in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a line with the following patterns:

`date`, `time` - `name`: `message`

A message may contain commas, dashes or colons. How can I split them?

Example:

```
03/05/2014, 16:24 - Steven: Thanks, keep you posted :D
```

Results:

```
grp[0]: 03/05/2014<br/>
grp[1]: 16:24<br/>
grp[2]: Steven<br/>
grp[3]: Thanks, keep you posted :D
```

Update:

The answer provided by Andrew Morton and Alexey Lebedev works:

```
/(.{10}), (.{5}) - (.*?): (.*)/
```

Comment: Does the line always match a pattern of 10 chars for the date, comma, space, 5 chars for the time, space, dash, space, name, colon, space,  message? Hint: `(.{10})` will match 10 chars.

Comment: the lengths of the date and time are fixed while name and message are not.

Comment: @wingkwong It is good that you have given us sample input and output, but please would you edit your question to include what you've tried so far so that we can help you with it? This site isn't really a code-writing service, it's more of a code-fixing site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the pattern

```
(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\s*,\s*(\d{2}:\d{2})\s*-\s*(.*?):\s*(.*)
```

Comment: Yep, works with completely conformant input. Both our patterns could also have leading caret ^ to force starts with matching

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Does that mean there is a bug at regex101.com: [my greedy version](https://regex101.com/r/6SRiVs/1)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, if you add a space between `:` and `D` in the end, then the group 3 matches everything up to the last colon: https://regex101.com/r/l6xlqy/1